# Is it possible to count characters across multiple input fields in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm dynamically adding FormGroups that contain FormControls to FormArray and display the form's controls in the UI as input fields. I'd like to count characters typed in the sectionContent field of each FormGroup added in the UI. This is perfectly possible with only one FormGroup as I can subscribe to valueChanges method, pass the length of value to a variable and then interpolate the variable in the UI. But is it possible with multiple dynamically added FormGroups and their FormControls? The problem is that each FormGroup requires a new variable injected into html code which I'm not sure is possible. Maybe there is another way of counting characters across multiple fields in the UI?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div formArrayName="section" *ngFor="let section of myForm.get('section').controls; let i = index">
   <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
               <textarea class="form-control" [id]="'sectionContent' + i" placeholder="Main Content" formControlName="sectionContent"></textarea>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
         (click)="addSectionButtonClick()">Add Section</button>
   </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-section',
    templateUrl: './create-section.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-section.component.css']
})
export class CreateSectionComponent implements OnInit {

myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            section: this.fb.array([
                this.addSectionFormGroup()
            ])
        });
}

addSectionButtonClick(): void {
        (this.myForm.get('section') as FormArray).push(this.addSectionFormGroup());
}

addSectionFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            sectionContent: ['', Validators.required]
        })
}
```

Comment: you want the consolidated count or count of each textarea ?

Comment: Get count and do what? I you want just to display on UI then use `pipes`, if you need the count for some calculations then get `FormArray` and get all `FormGroup` elements from it and get count for each one...

Comment: inside the loop `{{section.get('sectionContent').value?.length}}`

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in both, characters count and consolidated word count. There will also be dynamically added textareas that I'd like to consolidate and count words in real time. @miselking, for displaying in the UI, could you please give an example of a pipe?

Comment: @Eliseo, many thanks it worked. I didn't know we can query the form directly in the UI.

Comment: @CGG, you has a pipe sample in my anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a pipe. A pipe it's only a function that receive an argument and return a value. A simple count pipe can be

```
@Pipe({name: 'countPipe'})
export class CountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {

    return value?value.length+' characters, '+value.split(' ').length+' words'
                :'0 characters, 0 words';
  }
}
```

And you can use

```
{{section.get('sectionContent').value |countPipe}}
```

NOTE: Dont forget include the pipe as 'declarations in your  module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CountPipe ], //<--HERE
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```